# Shuffle columns

Tags: bash

What is the best way to reorder columns in `bash`?

Real example:

I have file ONE.txt contains:

```
firstName secondName telNumber
```

I want to create file SECOND.txt from the first file

```
secondName firstName telNubmer
```

How can I accomplish this? (Only swapping columns one row)

Comment: You can `awk ' {tmp = $1; $1 = $2; $2 = tmp;} ' your_file`

Comment: @AvinashRaj What's the difference?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Practically, there's not much difference, but Avinash's answer is slightly better since it doesn't require the creation of the `tmp` variable. BTW, it's not a good idea to post answers in comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use awk.

```
awk '{print $2,$1,$3}' infile > outfile
```

Comment: I love `awk` answers ;)

Answer (score 2):

And just for fun, here's a sed solution that's (almost) equivalent in action to Avinash Raj's awk command.

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]*\([^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]*\([^[:space:]]*\)[[:space:]]*/\2 \1 /' infile > outfile
```

Obviously, the awk solution is *much* easier to read. :) OTOH, the sed version copes with lines with more than 3 fields.

And if we can guarantee that the lines will *always* be *exactly* of the form

```
firstName secondName telNumber
```

with no extra spaces or other whitespace (eg tabs), we can condense the sed command down to:

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\)/\2 \1/'
```

---

I just did a quick timing test on a file containing 500,000 lines (generated using awk). The condensed sed version is 10 times slower than the awk version. I guessed it would be a bit slower, since sed is using regexes, but I didn't think it'd be *that* much slower.

FWIW, a Python equivalent of Avinash Raj's awk command is about twice as slow as the awk version.

---

I just re-read the question. It *appears* that the file in the OP only has one row of data.
In that case, we can do this very simply, using pure bash:

```
read a b c < ONE.txt;echo > SECOND.txt "$b $a $c"
```

Or *maybe* tilefrae is saying that they only want the swap to happen on the first row, and to make a plain copy of subsequent rows... If so, it's easy to modify either the awk or sed programs to do just that.